# I was added as a developer via Business Connect. Do I still need a developer membership?

Tags: ios, visual-studio, maui

I am working on a new App for my company that will be available for iOS and Android. I develop it in Visual Studio using .NET MAUI. I can deploy my development version of the App on an Android device without issues, but when I try to deploy to an iPhone, a dialog wants my Apple credentials.

I was invited as a developer in Apple's Business Connect by the product manager. The account that invited me is already used for publishing several Apps the company made in the past. I log in with my new Apple developer account, confirmed all legal notices, but when I try to connect to the iPhone from Visual Studio, I get the following error.

[image]

The Apple account is used for publishing Apps and I was invited as a developer. Do I need to enroll to the Apple Developer Program with my new account just to test the software on my iPhone?

Comment: Log in to https://appstoreconnect.Apple.com with your Apple ID and confirm that you are linked to the developer account. If you want to add a new device you may need to be granted certificates and identifiers access

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps you can follow to solve this error:

1. You need to create an App Store Connect API key: go to App Store
   Connect(you select Membership now), click User and Access, go to
   Keys tab, choose **App Store Connect API**, then generate an API
   Key.
2. You can open Visual Studio and go to Tools-> Options-> Xamarin->
   Apple Accounts -> Add-> Individual account, enter your API key.

Here are the documents you can refer to:

[Creating API Keys for App Store Connect API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/creating_api_keys_for_app_store_connect_api)

[Deploy an iOS app using hot restart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/hot-restart?view=net-maui-8.0#setup)

Comment: I am very sorry for my late response. I got additional permissions from our manager, so I should have full admin rights on our company's account. But I still do not see the options. When I log into Apple Connect, I see the "User and Access" field. If I click on it, I do not have a "Keys" tab. However, I have an "Integrations" tab that is mentioned in some guides, but there is no option for me to create an API Key.

Comment: You may have received the permission, and you can verify it.